# Access list policy with odd and even filtering

Tags: cisco, router, ipv4, acl, lab

I'm having some issues with some access list configuration regarding a topology. The lab requirements are:

- Deny any host with even-numbered IP addresses from the BM_R1 LAN from
  accessing hosts on the BM_R3 LAN.
- Hosts with odd-numbered IP addresses on the BM_R1 LAN should be able
  to ping any other destination.

The two networks to which the access list refers are `172.16.1.128/25` (R3 LAN) and `172.16.1.160` (R1 LAN). I've tried changing the wildcard bits to 0.0.0.254 for even IP addresses on both. I've also tried placing them on either R1 or R3, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: amusing.. try wildcard mask 0.0.0.1

Comment: please do not deride me.i'm kind of new to networking.0.0.0.1? i thought it should be 0.0.0.254.could you please explain?

Comment: No offense. I found the question amusing (not you) even if it has no practical use in the real world. Regarding the mask, why do you think it should be 0.0.0.254? All even numbers, when converted in binary will end with 0 , and all odd numbers, in binary, will end with 1. So you want to inspect only the last bit to filter even or odd numbers. Then the mask will be either 255.255.255.254 or 0.0.0.1.

Comment: for christs sake, it just doesn't work.the configuration I did was

access-list 20 deny 172.16.1.2 0.0.0.1
permit any

After that, i deleted the list and did the same with 255.255.255.254 instead of 0.0.0.1. it just doesnt work

Comment: This is basic thing. refer https://ciscotips.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/compute-an-access-list-to-match-even-or-odd-networks/ for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating ACLs in a Cisco router, you use wildcard masks. Where you have a bit set to `0` in the wildcard mask, that bit must exactly match in the address. Remember that addresses and masks, including wildcard masks, are really just 32-bit numbers. This only works for IPv4; IPv6 uses CIDR notation.

For example:

```
ip access-list 10 deny 192.168.2.0 0.0.1.255   ! denies anything between 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.255
ip access-list 10 deny 192.168.2.0 0.0.1.254   ! denies only even addresses between 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.255
ip access-list 10 deny 192.168.2.1 0.0.1.254   ! denies only odd addresses between 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.255
```

This is something that used to be taught in Cisco classes, but it's not actually very useful in the real world. If you must use non-contiguous wildcard masks, you should probably rethink the network design.

Comment: Ron Maupin, thanks for your reply. Regarding my certain network I did access-list 20 deny 172.16.1.1 0.0.0.254 
access-list 20 permit any 
but it did not work.

Comment: It may be how you applied the ACL. Standard ACLs should normally be applied `out`, closest to the destination, while extended ACLs should normally be applied `in`, closest to the source. Also, "_it did not work_," is not very descriptive of the problem.

Comment: hold on., so if want to stop an even-numbered host on R1 Lan from talking to a R3 Lan, we will apply the ACL on R3, right?

Comment: That depends. For a standard ACL, if you want to completely stop it from reaching R3, you apply it `out` on the R1 interface to R3, but if you want to prevent it from getting to the network on a single interface on R3, you apply it `out` on that interface on R3. For an extended ACL, you would apply it `in` on the interface of R1 where the network come into R1.

Comment: will it work by creating the list like this: conf t, ip access-list standard 20 and then the statements?

Comment: Yes. After you create the ACL, then apply it on the interface with `ip access-group 20 out`.

Comment: so Mr Ron, just to clarify it, let's suppose the router  has one serial interface and a fast ethernet one.I create the access list and apply it on the serial interface?on which router?I dont want to completely remove any trace of communication, I just want to filter out the even ones.

Comment: If you are using a standard ACL you would place it in the router interface leading to the destination network. If I understand your situation correctly, that would be the ethernet interface of R3. If you are using and extended access-list, it would be the interface closest to the source network: the ethernet interface of R1.

Comment: it'll be a standard access list, so I guess it'll be put on the fast ethernet interface of the destination router which is also the default gateway of the destination network?or the source?

Comment: For a standard access list, you put it as close to the destination as possible, so it would be the ethernet interface of the destination router. Since a standard access list does not include a destination address, if you put it any closer to the source, it will affect more traffic than you intend. Since an extended access list has a destination address, you want it close to the source. Think through your ACL to see what happens to the traffic headed to any destination after it passes through the ACL.

Comment: it worked, sir. 172.16.1.190 canNOT ping, while 172.16.1.189 can ping. thank you sir, really.thanks for your time.both you and everyone who replied.

Comment: If I have answered your question, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer, forever.

Comment: Right below the up/down arrows on the left of the answer.

Comment: just like that?

Comment: Yes. That did it.

Comment: I get it.still, thanks for your time. Now I only have one task left. I've already done myself the previous ones (excluding the odd/even filtering)